# Issues in progress bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on an angular app and making a progress bar using angular. I am facing two problems with my progress bar.

1. The 4th section of web development is titled from end. I want to make it straight same as first section
2. Text inside boxes coming in one after the other lines. I want them in one single line in parallel.

How can I resolve these issues?

```css
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: -2;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrap div:first-child {
  margin-left: -2%;
}

.progress {
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 0.5%;
  height: 30px;
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  transition: all 0.8s;
}

.progress:before,
.progress:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.8s;
  z-index: -1;
}

.progress:before {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-transform: skew(45deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(45deg);
  transform: skew(45deg);
}

.progress:after {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-transform: skew(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-45deg);
  transform: skew(-45deg);
}

.progress:hover:before,
.progress:hover:after {
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="progress">
    <div>MyData</div>
    <div>My Status</div>
  </div>
  <div class="progress">
    <div>MyData</div>
    <div>My Status</div>
  </div>
  <div class="progress">
    <div>MyData</div>
    <div>My Status</div>
  </div>
  <div class="progress">
    <div>MyData</div>
    <div>My Status</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the problems. What does "titled from end" mean? How to prevent text from wrapping has been thoroughly and extensively covered on SO. Give that a search.

Comment: Protip: [You don't need vendor prefixes for `transform`.](https://caniuse.com/transforms2d)

Comment: @isherwood If you see my attached image and see the last box. It's right hand side border is not in straight line. It is tilted from top and bottom. I want to make it straght line.

Comment: @isherwood  Regarding text. Could you please see my updated code now. I have two divs for myData and myStatus. I want them to be parallel to each other in one line

Answer (score 0):

Since you've put each label in a div element you might use flex layout on the parent. Otherwise, simply put both labels in the same div. Here I demonstrate both approaches.

```css
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: -2;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrap div:first-child {
  margin-left: -2%;
}

.progress {
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 0.5%;
  height: 30px;
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;    /* updated */
  justify-content: center; /* new */
  gap: 8px;                /* new */
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  transition: all 0.8s;
}

.progress:before,
.progress:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.8s;
  z-index: -1;
}

.progress:before {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transform: skew(45deg);
}

.progress:after {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-transform: skew(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-45deg);
  transform: skew(-45deg);
}

.progress:hover:before,
.progress:hover:after {
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="progress">
    <div>MyData</div>
    <div>My Status</div>
  </div>
  <div class="progress">
    <div>MyData</div>
    <div>My Status</div>
  </div>
  <div class="progress">
    <div>MyData My Status</div>
  </div>
  <div class="progress">
    <div>MyData My Status</div>
  </div>
</div>
```